# Primorial asymptote

Tags: primorial

Is there any asymptotic representation for the primorial, and if it is there is it a consequence of the Riemann hypothesis or is it proved to be true without assumptions.

Comment: There is an asymptotic expression in the FORMULA section at https://oeis.org/A002110

Comment: I know it was derived from the prime number theorem but doesn't that consider Riemann hypothesis to be true?

Comment: Some asymptotic estimates regarding the distribution of primes assume the Riemann Hypothesis, but the prime number theorem itself does not.

Comment: Thanks then, you should of put it as an answer though : )